# How to test button click event using jUnit in Android testcase

Tags: android

How could I write a testcase in Android JUnit, where I need to test whether a click event on button is working on not. Could anyone help me on this.

Regards
Deepak

Answer (score 1):

You should use android.test.TouchUtils to create a click simulation and override onClick of the button to test whether it is coming into that method. This could be done using a boolean which is set to true inside onClick